# Python: How to store a JSON Object to a variable using a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have pandas dataframe that i converted to a python dict and then to a json object, i now need to create a "for loop" of each object "as is" to do a POST call to a REST API.

How can i store one object at time in the exact format to variable?

any help is much appreciated, thank you in advance.

vik

```
[
{
    "Field_1": "4321",
    "Field_11": "Store",
    "Field_15": "Laptop",
    "Field_6": "Dell",
    "Field_8": "PRECISION",
    "Field_132": "7560",
    "Field_10": "abcde",
    "Field_133": "43245",
    "Field_13": "abcd",
    "Field_161": "Canada",
    "Field_2": "11/25/2021",
    "Field_5": "Dell",
    "Field_41": NaN
},
{
    "Field_1": "76543",
    "Field_11": "Store",
    "Field_15": "Laptop",
    "Field_6": "Dell",
    "Field_8": "PRECISION",
    "Field_132": "7560",
    "Field_10": "23dfgt",
    "Field_133": "876543",
    "Field_13": "abfgdc",
    "Field_161": "USA",
    "Field_2": "11/25/2021",
    "Field_5": "Dell",
    "Field_41": NaN
}
```

Comment: To clarify, you'd like to iterate through and store each of these dictionaries in a variable?

Comment: yes, you are right, create a for loop iterating through each of these dictionaries into a variable

Comment: so basically you want to create new variables for all keys in dict ?

Comment: iterate through each of the JSON objects and store it in one variable using aloop.